# How can I create a h1 as in the example?

Tags: css

I want to create the h1 header as an example below. I saw this type of header at some website which I could not remember it's address right now. If I'd remember, I'd copy it from their website. Unfortunally I forgot. Here's the the PSD screen-shot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/0707YR.png))</sub>

Anyway, no matter what I've tried I still could not get the result. What I got is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/DlOlQZ.png))</sub>

Here's my code:

```
div.big-header div.header-left h1 {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    background: #c00000;
    font: bold 35px "Open Sans";
    padding: 1px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

and here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhsxk6x9/)

Question: How can I create the header as example above (first picture)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhsxk6x9/3/)**

**Updated** **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhsxk6x9/5/)**

**Update:** Just added display:inline, line-height with box-decoration-break along with your code..

CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    background: #c00000;
    font: bold 35px sans-serif;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    /* newly added code */
    display:inline;
    line-height:44px;
   -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
     box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what exactly you changed, and how this change works, to improve your answer (not only for OP, but for other people with the same issue).

Comment: Thank you but the H and w letters are not aligned correctly. w letter is at has no padding from left as H letter does. Image: http://i.hizliresim.com/pR5g9m.png

Comment: @emreaydin149: I updated my code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `span` inside your `h1`:

```
h1 {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 35px sans-serif;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

h1 > span {
    background: #c00000;
}
```

And:

```
<h1><span>How to create a page with PHP?</span></h1>
```